# Python3 cannot get XML element value with lxml.etree.find

Tags: python-3.x, find, response, lxml

I'm trying to handle a POST response where I get an XML.
The result is saved as bytes b'':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result xmlns="http://something.com/Schema/V2/Result">
    <success>false</success>
    <returnType>ERROR</returnType>
    <errors>
        <error>
            <message>Invalid signature</message>
            <code>3002</code>
        </error>
    </errors>
</result>
```

Code:

```
from lxml import etree as et

root_node = et.fromstring(response.content)
print('{}'.format(root_node.find('.//returnType')))
return_type = root_node.find('.//returnType').text
```

The print statement return None, so the find().text throws exception.

If I iterate trough the childs with for I get the node but with namespace that I cannot handle.

```
for tag in root_node.getchildren():
    print(tag)

<Element {http://something.com/Schema/V2/Result}returnType at 0x7f6c95542648>
```

How can I get the XML nodes and their values? I've tried the stackoverflow answers for kinda similar problems but nothing works. Tried using regex to remove the schema and adding a prefix to the NS.

EDIT: tried the answer and getting the standard error that I cannot get the nodes.

```
    /usr/bin/python3 /home/samoa/Scripts/Python/lxml_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/samoa/Scripts/Python/lxml_test.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(root.find("returnType", root.nsmap).text)
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 1537, in lxml.etree._Element.find (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:58520)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/lxml/_elementpath.py", line 288, in find
    it = iterfind(elem, path, namespaces)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/lxml/_elementpath.py", line 277, in iterfind
    selector = _build_path_iterator(path, namespaces)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/lxml/_elementpath.py", line 234, in _build_path_iterator
    raise ValueError("empty namespace prefix is not supported in ElementPath")
ValueError: empty namespace prefix is not supported in ElementPath
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the namespace map to the `find()` method. As `http://something.com/Schema/V2/Result` is the default namespace in your document, that's all you have to do:

```
return_type_element = root_node.find('.//returnType', root_node.nsmap)
```

or:

```
return_type_element = root_node.find('returnType', root_node.nsmap)
```

Moreover, the `str.format()` in:

```
print('{}'.format(root_node.find('.//returnType')))
```

is unnecessary and can be shortened to:

```
return_type_element = root_node.find('returnType', root_node.nsmap)
print(return_type_element)

# <Element {http://something.com/Schema/V2/Result}returnType at 0x107c28bc0>
```

If, however, you want to print `return_type_element` as XML, use the `lxml.etree.tostring()` function:

```
print(ET.tostring(return_type_element))

# b'<returnType xmlns="http://something.com/Schema/V2/Result">ERROR</returnType>\n    '
```

Thus, your `return_type` can be obtained through:

```
return_type = root_node.find('returnType', root_node.nsmap).text
```

---

My test script is:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from lxml import etree as ET

content = b'''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result xmlns="http://something.com/Schema/V2/Result">
    <success>false</success>
    <returnType>ERROR</returnType>
    <errors>
        <error>
            <message>Invalid signature</message>
            <code>3002</code>
        </error>
    </errors>
</result>
'''

root = ET.fromstring(content)
emptyns = root.nsmap[None]
print(root.find("{%s}returnType" % (emptyns)).text)

# step-by-step

root = ET.fromstring(content)
print("Root element: %s" % (root))

emptyns = root.nsmap[None]
print("Empty namespace: %s" % (emptyns))

return_type_element = root.find("{%s}returnType" % (emptyns))
print("<returnType> element: %s" % (return_type_element))
print("<returnType> element as XML: %s" % (ET.tostring(return_type_element)))

return_type = return_type_element.text
print('<returnType> text: %s' % (return_type))

# children

for element in root.getchildren():
    print("Element tag (with namespace): %s" % (element.tag))
    _, _, tag = element.tag.rpartition("}")
    print("Element tag (without namespace): %s" % (tag))
```

Its result is:

```
ERROR
Root element: <Element {http://something.com/Schema/V2/Result}result at 0x102f63188>
Empty namespace: http://something.com/Schema/V2/Result
<returnType> element: <Element {http://something.com/Schema/V2/Result}returnType at 0x102f630c8>
<returnType> element as XML: b'<returnType xmlns="http://something.com/Schema/V2/Result">ERROR</returnType>\n    '
<returnType> text: ERROR
Element tag (with namespace): {http://something.com/Schema/V2/Result}success
Element tag (without namespace): success
Element tag (with namespace): {http://something.com/Schema/V2/Result}returnType
Element tag (without namespace): returnType
Element tag (with namespace): {http://something.com/Schema/V2/Result}errors
Element tag (without namespace): errors
```

Comment: No this does not work. Have tried it already. It just throws ValueError "empty namespace prefix is not supported in ElementPath". As I said at the end of the question, that I tried to add a prefix to the nsmap and it also didn't work.

Comment: I added my test script and its result to my answer.

Comment: Copied your code and run it. Got the same error that I cannot fix. I edited the question with the error.

Comment: Could you give me the version of your lxml, please? `python -c "from lxml.etree import LIBXML_VERSION, LXML_VERSION; print(LIBXML_VERSION, LXML_VERSION)"`

Comment: It returns (2, 9, 4) (3, 7, 1, 0). And I cannot change or update the versions because the platform that I program needs this versions. So I'm looking for another way to parse the XML.

Comment: I updated and successfully tested my script for lxml 3.7.1. Could you test it, please?

Comment: Thanks! This last one works. I tried something like this before with format and it didn't work probably because {}.